# Spring MVC user verification

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a small application using Spring MVC. It's some kind of billboard where users can put content of several types. I have successfully configured the security for the different roles in my app (User, Admin, Anon) using the security-config.xml. Now you have to be logged to post, only Admin users can see the admin panel, etc.

Now my problem is that I have to set the security for each user, i.e. that the user modifying the content is the user that made the content. The most directly approach is of course check in Java if both the user logged and the creator of the content are the same, just before I call my function. Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/listing/deletecontent.html")
public String deleteUserContent(@RequestParam String contentId) {
    //Get the logged user
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User user = userService.loadUserByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());

    //Check if the user logged and the content owner are the same
    if (user == the_user_that_created_the_content)
          listingService.deleteContent(Integer.valueOf(contentId));

    return "redirect:/listing/usercontent.html";
}
```

I don't why but I don't like this approach. It's just "copy-paste" the same verification over and over again everywhere I need it, and it just doesn't feel right. I was thinking that maybe Spring has some type of feature that allows me to set in the security-config.xml, maybe calling a class to make this verification for every URL with the *contentId* parameter and then redirect it to the "real" URL if it passes the test. I don't know, thats what I want to ask you. ¿What do you think of this approach? ¿Maybe I'm being too picky and it's not that bad? ¿You know a "better" way to do it?

Thanks so much in advance,
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to close look at [expression-based access control chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/el-access.html#d0e5622) in Spring Security reference. So, as far I understand, you shouldn't check permissions yourself -- just use `@PreAuthorize` annotation. Try ACL module or if it doesn't meet your requirement, probably better implements custom `PermissionEvaluator`.

P.S. Also what about something like this:  `@PreAuthorize("principal.id == #content.createdBy.id")`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this was exactly the kind of input I was looking for.